# show another component as soon as the user logs in

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a use case where the user gets to log in. As soon as the user gets log in, another component should be shown. This is not working to me. I have to hit the login button again to show another component or has to refresh the page.

Here is what I have done

This is the parent component

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    user: state.loginReducer
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    hasToken: false
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { user } = this.props;
    window.chrome.storage.sync.get(['user_token'], result => {
      if ((user && user.access_token) || result.user_token) {
        console.log('user_token in cdm', result, user);
        this.setState({ hasToken: true })
      }
    })
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.user !== nextProps.user) {
        window.chrome.storage.sync.get(['user_token'], result => {
          if (nextProps.user.length || result.user_token) {
            this.setState({ hasToken: true })
          }
        })
    }
  }

  anotherComponent() { // just to show the demo 
    return (
      <div class="content">
        component to show when the user logs in
      </div>
    )
  }

  render() {
    const { hasToken } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
            { !hasToken ? <Login /> : this.anotherComponent()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(App);
```

**login.js**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  userLogin: user => dispatch(login(user))
})


class Login extends React.Component {
  state = {
    user: {
      email:"",
      password: "",
      grant_type: "password"
    }
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({user: {...this.state.user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}})
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.userLogin(this.state.user);
  }

    render() {
    const { user } = this.state;
        return (
            <Grid>
                <Row className="pad-10">
                    <Col sm={12} md={6} mdOffset={3}>
                        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <FormGroup controlId="email">
                                <ControlLabel>Email</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl
                  type="email"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  name="email"
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  value={user.email}
                />
                            </FormGroup>

                            <FormGroup controlId="password">
                                <ControlLabel>Password</ControlLabel>
                                    <FormControl
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    name="password"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    value={user.password}
                  />
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                    <Button type="submit">Sign in</Button>
                            </FormGroup>
                        </Form>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Grid>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

I am not using any router concept so What I wanted to do is when user hits the login button, if the login is successful, the token is respond from the server and that is checked so that if it is successful, the user will be shown another component.

UPDATE

```
export const login = action(LOGIN, 'user');
export const loginSuccess = action(LOGIN_SUCCESS, 'data');
export const loginFailure = action(LOGIN_FAILURE, 'error');
```

reducer code

```
const initialState = {
   fetching: false,
   error: null,
   user: []
 }

 function loginReducer(state=initialState, action) {
   switch (action.type) {
     case LOGIN:
      return {...state, fetching: true}
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {...state, fetching: false, user: action.data.access_token}
    case LOGIN_FAILURE:
      return {...state, fetching: false, error: action.error}
     default:
      return state;
   }
 }

 export default loginReducer;
```

Comment: Show your reducers/actions to us, please

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how does `window.chrome.storage.sync` works, but obvious solution (at the first glance) is:

```
  // parent component
  render() {
    const { user } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
            { !user ? <Login /> : this.anotherComponent()}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

You have to get user from your state
I'll provide more details when you bring your reducers/actions

Answer (score 0):

The problem your code is not working is because the `App` component is only rendered once irrespective of weather the user is logged in or not. So later when the user is logged in, your app component is not re-rendered.

There could be many ways to solve this. What I suggest you to do is something like this:
pass an `onUserLogin` callback to Component something like

```
<LoginModal isModalOpen={isModalOpen} onLoginClick={this.onLoginClick} />
```

Then do a `setState` inside the `onLoginClick` function to make sure component is rendered with changed props.

```
  onLoginClick = () => {
    if (!this.state.isUserLoggedIn) {
      this.setState({
        isModalOpen:!this.state.isModalOpen,
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: I am not using any modal and I did not understand the purpose. Can you help me based on my code, please?